# Чередование гласных

Tags: орфография

В корнях с чередованием а (я) – им, а (я) – ин пишутся «им» и «ин», если дальше следует суффикс «а». Например: сжать, сжимать, понять, понимать,

напоминать, напомнить - а где здесь чередование а (я) – ин?

Или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Существует две группы глаголов с корнем **МН/МИН (А)**, которые имеют разные оттенки значений, при этом чередование ИН/Я происходит только во второй группе (поминать - помянуть):

1)   Помнить (удерживать в памяти); вспомнить/вспоминать (восстановить, возобновить в памяти;   напомнить/напоминать (освежить в чьей-л. памяти что-л.).

2) Пом**ин**ать/пом**я**нуть - молиться о здоровье живого или об упокоении умершего.

**МНИТЬ**, разг. - думать, считать, полагать.

А вообще чередование **А(Я)/ИМ, А(Я)/ИН** характерно для глаголов с историческим корнем **(Н)ЯТЬ (=брать)**: понять, обнять, принять, занять и др.

Comment: Sibylla, к сожалению, во многих учебниках слова напоминать, напомнить приводят именно как пример чередования ИН/Я

Comment: А в каких учебниках вы видели?

Comment: Мне кажется, что это правило надо применять в обобщенном виде для разных групп глаголов, так как здесь важно отметить появление форманта ИМ/ИН перед суффиксом А в глаголах несовершенного вида (если  безударный  гласный И нельзя проверить, то  он определяется по суффиксу А). А вот исходная форма совершенного вида может или содержать   гласный А/Я (обнять/обнимать, сжать/сжимать, понять/понимать),  или не иметь гласного вообще (запомнить/запоминать, также: собрать/собирать, сотру/стираю и др.).

Answer (score 0):

> *к сожалению, во многих учебниках слова напоминать, напомнить приводят именно как пример чередования ИН/Я*

Это очень странно, поскольку рассматриваемое чередование проявляется посчти исключительно в бесприставочных глаголах, у которых парная видовая форма образуется по особой схеме: не с помощью стандартного суффикса "вторичной имперфективации" ива/ыва, а как раз с помощью этого чередования.

Напомнить - напоминать - это другая схема, тоже нестандартная, с помощью *паронимичной* пары "помнить-поминать"  но не связанная напрямую с чередованием

Answer (score 0):

> ***напоминать…*** - а где здесь чередование ***а(я) – ин?***

Чередование ***ин/я***  имеет, к примеру, место в однокоренных с глаголом ***напоминать*** глаголах ***помИНать/помЯнуть, упомИНать/упомЯнуть…***

Такое же чередование в корне можно найти и в паре глаголов с приставкой ***на: 
 напомИНать/напомЯнуть.***

***Напомянуть***   — имевшая когда-то место форма глагола сов. вида (*= напомнить*), сохранившаяся в какой-то мере и по сей день:

> [**напомяну́ть**](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/191438/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C)
>
> *сов. перех. и неперех. разг.-сниж.*
>
> Заставить кого-либо вспоминать о ком-либо или о чём-либо.
>
> ***Толковый словарь Ефремовой. 2000***